# How to use javascript function on dynamically created element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I created an `li` using

```
  static make(string, el) {
    var wrapper= document.createElement((el || 'div'));
    wrapper.innerHTML = string;
    return wrapper.firstChild;
  }

  static makeLi(string) {
    return this.make(string, "ul");
  }
```

This is the template for the string I'm passing in:

```
return `
  <li class="truer-companion">
    <a class="truer-companion-link" href="${url}">${this.escapeHTML(title)}</a>
    ${Vote.form_container(article_id)}
  </li>
`;
```

Where it is passed to a function with this

```
  static createVoteForms(el) {
    console.log(el);
    let foo = (el || document).getElementsByClassName("bar");
```

Which throws the error

`Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: (el || document).getElementsByClassName is not a function`

But somewhere else where I don't run `createVoteForms` with an argument it works fine.

And when I log `el` the output is `#text` but has attributes like an object.

Comment: Where do you call `createVoteForms ` and what are you passing in? If what you pass in doesn't implement `getElementsByClassName` then this isn't going to work

Comment: *And when I log el the output is #text but has attributes like an object.* so your passing in the string `#text`? so that'll do  `'#text'.getElementsByClassName("bar");` which obviously ins't going to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And when I log el the output is #text but has attributes like an object.

A DOM has lots of different kinds of nodes.

When you call `createElement`, you create an *element node*.

The value you are passing to `createVoteForms` is a *text node*. This is how text is represented in a DOM. (It wouldn't do much good if you could have a `<p>` but had no way of putting text inside it!).

Text nodes do not have a `getElementsByClassName` method (because text nodes cannot contain other nodes).

Comment: OK, then how do I change `make` to return an `element` node rather than a `text` node?

Comment: You could return `wrapper`, or you could test `string` to make sure it starts with an HTML tag.

Comment: The string does, and worked fine when I was just using jquery for it. But I added the template it uses to my question. And I don't want to return a `ul`, which is what the wrapper is, I want to return the `li` as an `element` node.

Comment: @MCB — It doesn't start with an HTML tag, it starts with a new line and a bunch of spaces.

Comment: Just checked it out, and you're right it was the whitespace. I wrote all my templates assuming everything was whitespace agnostic. Easy enough to fix with `trim()`. For the record if anyone else has a similar problem replacing `firstChild` with `children[0]` also worked.